# How to wait for an external response with callbacks?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, networking

I've been searching quite a bit on this topic, but I think I'm not using the right words for searching any of this stuff, because I've not found an answer yet.

I'm looking for a way to make a process wait for a (specific) response of an external source.

In more detail, in a standard socket connection, I ask my remote endpoint for a certain value via a socket.send, how can I "catch" their reply? The idea that I already had was to send some sort of identifier along to determine what request this belongs to.

Is there a way to efficiently achieve this? (Performance is rather important). I'm currently using .NET2.0 if that's relevant information.

Some example code:

```
    public void AskForReply()
    {
        //Send to connected endpoint
    }

    public void ReceiveReply(IAsyncResult response)
    {
        //Do stuff with the response
    }
```

I've been working out several ideas in my head. But they all feel really messy and not very efficient. Is there a design pattern for this? Are there standards for this behavior?

And help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) didn't work?

Comment: Why is .net 2 a requirement, this is not supported and very out of date, no operating systems support this version of .net anymore

Comment: Also why are you using sockets and not a more mature technology, It takes a lot of boiler plating to make a socket solution work correctly and build a messaging system on top of it, why not just use something like WCF

Comment: @TheGeneral Started because Unity at least supported .Net2.0. I'm not going to use a more "mature technology" because I don't want all the unnecessary overhead. I also want full control myself. WCF is not performant at all compared to sockets for example.

Comment: @yazanpro Your example lists asynchronous operations on 1 socket instance. It, in no way, waits for external communication for a callback, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: All valid points, however I think you need to do some more research, this question is not really a good fit for stack overflow as it's too broad and no real value to future readers, I wish you the best of luck though

Comment: @TheGeneral I worked on an application during an internship about a year ago that did exactly what I think I now need. When a call was made from the front-end (typescript) to the server, you could pass along a callback. This callback was stored in a dictionary and the message carried an identifier as to what callback the response belonged to. But I can't for the life of me remember how this was done or how this was called. Maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who runs into a similar problem, I have found a way to make an asynchronous call synchronous (which is essentially what you are trying to achieve).

```
    EventWaitHandle waitHandler;
    string replyMessage;

    void string AskForReply()
    {
        //Already requesting something...
        if(waitHandler != null) { return; }
        waitHandler = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

        //Send a request to a remote service

        waitHandler.WaitOne(timeout);

        //Will reply null (or the default value) if the timeout passes.
        return replyMessage;
    }

    void ReceiveReply(string message)
    {
        //We never asked for a reply? (Optional)
        if (waitHandler != null) { return; }
        replyMessage = message;
        //Process your reply

        waitHandler.Set();
        waitHandler = null;
    }
```

It's probably a good idea to put the EventWaitHandle and the reply message in a class for better and cleaner management. You can then even put this object in a dictionary along with a key that you can use handle multiple requests at once (do keep in mind they are synchronous and will block your thread until the timeout or the waithandle is set).